# Orcad/PSpice - How to add V0, V1 for PSpice

Tags: orcad, pspice

I have my Circuit and PSpice solves it correctly. However, I want to measure the voltage across a specific place, V0. How do I add the marker V0 into my circuit and have PSpice solve for it?

Answer (score 1):

"Across a specific place" means between two nodes within the circuit, correct?
In this case you can select from the menu "mark advanced" the option "mark voltage differential".